# Avoid spilling of text to margin when using R markdown and knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

While generating a pdf file using `rmarkdown` and `knitr`, how to avoid spilling of text of `R` console output to the margins? For example,

````
---
title: "Illustration"
author: "Temp"
date: "Monday, April 06, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

Spilling of R output.

```{r}
library("tm")
data("acq")
str(acq)
```
````

Comment: You can set the width of the print-out.

Comment: See knitr options here: http://yihui.name/knitr/options/

Comment: @RomanLuštrik ried to adjust the width with ```{r set-options, cache=FALSE}
options(width = 50)
rnorm(100)
library("tm")
data("acq")
str(acq)
```
But adjustment is occuring only for `rnorm(100)`. It is ignored for `str(acq)`.

Comment: Try setting the width in the chunk option (`opts_chunk$set(width = 50)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the most consistent way for me to deal with this is to use the `width` and `strict.width` options to the `str()` [function](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/str). The `width` option specifies the page width to be used and is supposed to inherit from the active options() setting for width. But, I haven't always found this consistent. The `strict.width` allows you to control how the excess text is handled (cut, wrapped).

````
---
title: "Illustration"
author: "Temp"
date: "Monday, April 06, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

Spilling of R output.

```{r}
library("tm")
data("acq")
str(acq,width=80,strict.width="cut")
```
````